# Ubuntu/Gparted won't show all my hard drive capacity

Tags: hard-drive, gparted

My Asus Laptop's main, internal hard drive has a total 621.4 GB of space, however, Gparted is only showing a total of 332.06 GB of total data space among my partitions.

Its pretty much telling me that I lost 289.34 GB somewhere.

When I made the switch to Ubuntu, it was a full switch, no more old OS, so I don't know where that 290 went off to.

The only thing I know that might help, is that this RoG Asus had some sort of quick start, very basic OS on it, along with standard Windows, but I could have sworn I have gotten rid of that feature all together. Truthfully, I don't know if the 621.4 GB included that OS or not.

I'd really like to know what happened to my vanishing 289.34 GB, and would love to get it back.

Thank you.

EDIT: Here are some screen shots. Note, I was in the middle of setting up a dual boot with Windows, but the Windows Disk told me that I needed to make a new partition. Hence why I went to GParted in the first place.

System Details:

[image]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t1.0-9/10606164_901124229916929_5669524821752624060_n.jpg))</sub>

GParted Info for the standard Ubuntu Partition:

[image]

GParted info for a small partition that the Windows Disk created:

[image: 29.97 GB]

For another source on how big my harddrive is, its an Asus RoG G51Vx: http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/G51Vx/specifications/

Here is the output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d11a5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   616753151   308375552   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       616755198   625141759     4193281    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       616755200   625141759     4193280   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Here is the output of `sudo parted -l`:

```
~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d11a5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   616753151   308375552   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       616755198   625141759     4193281    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       616755200   625141759     4193280   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C disk` :

```
`*-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST9320421AS
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: SD14
       serial: 5TJ0VT78
       size: 298GiB (320GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=000d11a5
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVDRAM GSA-T50N
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: RR07
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Comment: Well, people could try and guess, or you can post some evidence: Gparted screenshot, output of <df- h> and <sudo fdisk -l>. Which do you prefer?

Comment: I edited my post to include links to screenshots.

Comment: No, just one internal HDD (and if it means anything, a 3TB external HDD)

Comment: I just checked the specs from the linked website. It says: `640G(320Gx2),7200rpm`. So you do have two internal disks. And the listed space (298GiB) seems about right for a 320GB disk. The second disk `/dev/sdb` probably doesn't have a correct partition table. In GParted, there's an option in the *View* menu called *Device Information*. Enable it, post a screenshot. Or simpler and more complete: The output of `sudo fdisk -l; sudo parted -l`.

Comment: Got pictures up on original post.

Comment: @Dracul Always, always, copy-paste the output of commands instead of using screenshots. That said, your second hard disk doesn't seem to be detected at all by GParted or `parted -l`. `sdb` is a HP flash drive. You aren't using LVM or RAID. So why isn't your second hard disk showing up? O.o Well, let me look around to see how to list unformatted devices as well. One more command to try: `sudo lshw -C disk`.

Comment: @muru, Just corrected myself and turned the outputs into text, and posted the output for 'sudo lshw -C disk'

Comment: Are there actually two drives inside the machine? If so are they configured as a RAID 1 array in the Bios?

Comment: I just checked my BIOS and might of came across a worse problem, there is only one HDD that the Asus/American Megatrends BIOS recognizes. In BIOS, I saw these, no second HDD mentioned, and it wasn't set to RAID.: 

BIOS>Boot>Hard Disk Drives:
1st Drive [HDD:POI-ST9320421AS]

BIOS> Advanced >IDE Configuration:
SATA Operation Mode  [Enhanced]
AHCI Port0 [Hard Disk]
AHCI Post1 [ATAPI CDROM]

Comment: Pleasecheck in BIOS / Hardware setup howthe disks are configured there, if both disks are visible and if they are set as same type raid and so on.